# Confuse with xsd schema and xml file elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've one schema xsd file. In that xsd file, i've confused with "choice".

For e.g
myschema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Emp">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="E1" />
        <xs:element ref="E2" />
        <xs:element ref="E3" />
        <xs:element ref="E4" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

myxmlfile1.xml - e.g 1

**EDIT:** Root element Employee added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employee>
  <Emp>
    <E1></E1>
    <E2></E2>
  </Emp>
</Employee>
```

myxmlfile2.xml - e.g 2

**EDIT:** Root element Employee added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employee>
  <Emp>
    <E1></E1>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <E2></E2>
  </Emp>
</Employee>
```

In these 2 xml files, according to schema, myxmlfile1.xml is correct else myxmlfile2.xml is correct??

clear me with explanation...

**EDIT:**

```
Here i want to know,
```

- Emp element can have both E1 and E2 child elements in any order (or) ??
- can have anyone of the child element i.e, E1 or E2(can not have both).??

Comment: If you don't know which of your examples is valid, it can only be because you have not paid attention to the answers already provided to this question.  Read them again, carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Think of xs:choice with maxOccurs=unbounded as meaning you can have as many elements as you like, and each element must be either a foo or a bar or a baz (or whatever the list in your xs:choice happens to be).

Comment: My query updated. Emp is not a root element. Employee is the root element. now say me the solution plz.

Comment: Your change to the question has no impact at all on my explanation of what xs:choice means.

Comment: You didn't ask whether it was correct. You asked what it meant. It can only be described as correct if it meets some requirement, and you haven't given a requirement.... Sorry, looking back at the question, it seems you keep changing the question. That makes it hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second example is neither valid nor [well-formed xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)(XML cannot contain more than one root element).

The first one is fine, because of *xs:choice*  and *maxOccurs="unbounded"* used together.

*xs:choice* forces you to select **just one** of the provided elements, while
*maxOccurs="unbounded"* allows you to do it as much times as you want.

Order does not matter in this case, e.g. such document will be valid as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Emp>
  <E4></E4>
  <E4></E4>
  <E2></E2>
  <E3></E3>
</Emp>
```

Comment: Sorry dude. i've updated my query. here Emp is not a root element.

now say to me, which example is correct.?